# Filtering fields on returned relationship in Laravel4?

Tags: php, database, laravel, filtering, eager-loading

When using eager loading in Laravel 4 we can load relationships using the following:

```
$user = User::with('role')->find(1);
```

Which will return the representation of the user and we can access the representation of the role via

```
$user->roles();
```

Now we can also filter the eager loading using a where

```
$user = User::with(array('role' => function($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%key%');
}))->find(1);
```

Which will return the user representation with the roles being populated only where the role name field contains `key`.

We can limit the fields returned on the representation of the user by adding a `select()` constraint.

```
$user = User::with(array('role' => function($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%key%');
}))->select('email')->find(1);
```

Which will only return the `email` and `id` fields on the user representation but all fields on the role representation.

I was hoping I could limit the fields returned on the relationship (for use in an api) but I cannot seem to find a way; I have tried the two below methods.

```
$user = User::with(array('role' => function($query) {
    $query->select('name');
}))->find(1);
```

and

```
$user = User::with('role')->select('role.name')->find(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which columns you want in the relation definition.

```
// app/model/User.php
<?php

class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Role')->select(array('id', 'name'));
    }
}
```

First param in the `array('id', 'name')` array, is the foreign key column on roles table that connects it to the users table.

**Edit** (according to your comment)

I tried a couple of things and you were on the right path in first example. Just a little change:

```
$user = User::with(array('role' => function($query) {
    $query->select(array('id', 'name'));
}))->find(1);
```

This should work.

Comment: Issue is that I don't know what columns I am after until the api user requests it with something like `?fields=email,role:(name)` in the query string.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, it does have an effect in that the named fields are listed first in the roles representation, but it doesn't limit the response to only those fields!

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't filter what columns are returned as as such is not a viable solution if you want to prevent grabbing a rather large column (e.g. a blog post contents) this can be used to filter what columns are visible when represented as an array or Json.

```
//fetch the unfiltered relationship
$user = User::with('roles')->find($id);

//loop over each model in that relationship and set the visible properties
$user->roles->each(function($role){
    $role->setVisible(['id', 'name', 'pivot']);
});
```